# postgresql: update multiple values within one jsonb object

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have been facing a problem recently regarding JSONB data type in my Postgresql DB.

I have a rather complex structure of my column (let's say the table is called RATING and the column name FOOD_VALUE - making it up) which goes, for example, as follows:

```
{
  "food": {
            "type": {
                     "id": 1,
                      "name": "good"
                    },
            "category": {
                          "id": 2,
                          "name": "Vegetables"
                       },
            "others": {
                       "descr": "It's all good"
                     }
         }
}
```

This is an example, the actual one might have up to hundreds of values (nested of course).

I want to update several values (in this example two -> food.type.name + food.category.id) without modifying the structure itself.

This is the desired output:

```
{
  "food": {
            "type": {
                     "id": 1,
                      "name": "not bad"
                    },
            "category": {
                          "id": 1,
                          "name": "Vegetables"
                       },
            "others": {
                       "descr": "It's all good"
                     }
         }
}
```

With JSONB_SET I can only manipulate one record within the same column -> RATING.FOOD_VALUE ... I know I can nest them as well, but considering I need to update 40+ values, this might become a hell to read (and therefore maintain)

So this:

```
UPDATE rating 
SET food_value = jsonb_set(
      jsonb_set(food_value,'{food, type, name}', '"not bad"')::jsonb
      ,'{food, category, id}','"1"'::jsonb)
WHERE ....
```

is definitely a no-go ..

Another way of achieving this is to use JSON_BUILD_OBJECT:

```
UPDATE rating 
SET food_value = food_value 
   || jsonb_build_object('food', jsonb_build_object('type', jsonb_build_object('name', 'not bad')))
   || jsonb_build_object('food', jsonb_build_object('category', jsonb_build_object('id', 1)))
   ... and so on
WHERE ....
```

This looks a bit more promising when it comes to maintenance, readability, etc.. but the problem I faced here is that it changes the structure of the JSON files format :( so the query above will result in

```
{
  "food": {
            "type": {
                      "name": "not bad"
                    },
            "category": {
                          "id": 1
                       }
         }
}
```

Any idea how to get out of this predicament? I need to find a way how to update dozens of fields inside a complex JSON structure without modification of the structure itself (just values)

Comment: You'd have to unnest and aggregate the JSON again. I guess the `jsonb_set` method might be the most readable one. JSON is always messier in SQL than a normalized schema; that's kind of in the nature of things.

Comment: could you provide an example pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create type t_json_val as (path text[], val jsonb);

create or replace function jsonb_mset(a jsonb, variadic b t_json_val[])
    returns jsonb
    immutable
    language plpgsql
as $$
-- Set multiple jsonb values at once
declare
    bb t_json_val;
begin
    foreach bb in array b loop
        a := jsonb_set(a, bb.path, bb.val);
    end loop;
    return a;
end $$;
```

```
select jsonb_pretty(jsonb_mset('{
  "food": {
            "type": {
                     "id": 1,
                      "name": "good"
                    },
            "category": {
                          "id": 2,
                          "name": "Vegetables"
                       },
            "others": {
                       "descr": "It''s all good"
                     }
         }
}',
('{food, type, name}', '"not bad"'),
('{food, category, id}', '"1"')));

┌──────────────────────────────────────┐
│             jsonb_pretty             │
├──────────────────────────────────────┤
│ {                                   ↵│
│     "food": {                       ↵│
│         "type": {                   ↵│
│             "id": 1,                ↵│
│             "name": "not bad"       ↵│
│         },                          ↵│
│         "others": {                 ↵│
│             "descr": "It's all good"↵│
│         },                          ↵│
│         "category": {               ↵│
│             "id": "1",              ↵│
│             "name": "Vegetables"    ↵│
│         }                           ↵│
│     }                               ↵│
│ }                                    │
└──────────────────────────────────────┘
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cdfd9448eb5c287232ffa900411c5615)

Comment: ok... all I gotta say is: WOW!!!! that is exactly it.. I was about to write my own function because it looked like there is no "built-in" tool to use.. but you nailed it :) thx a lot.. saved a ton of my time!!